# При решении задачи в PyCharm все отлично но на платформе Stepik выдает ошибку

Tags: python, list

Подсписки списка ️️

Подсписок — часть другого списка. Подсписок может содержать один элемент, несколько, и даже ни одного. Например, [1], [2], [3] и [4] — подсписки списка [1, 2, 3, 4]. Список [2, 3] — подсписок списка [1, 2, 3, 4], но список [2, 4] не подсписок списка [1, 2, 3, 4], так как элементы 22 и 44 во втором списке не смежные. Пустой список — подсписок любого списка. Сам список — подсписок самого себя, то есть список [1, 2, 3, 4] подсписок списка [1, 2, 3, 4].

На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая символы. Из данной строки формируется список. Напишите программу, которая выводит список, содержащий все возможные подсписки списка, включая пустой список.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая символы, отделенные символом пробела.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести указанный список, содержащий все возможные подсписки, включая пустой список в соответствии с примерами.

Примечание. Порядок списков одинаковой длины должен соответствовать порядку их вхождения в основной список.

Тест
Входные данные: a b
Выходные данные: [[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b']]

Мое решение

```
y = [[]]
v = []
counter = 0

while True:
    x = input().split()
    if x:
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            v = []
            for j in x:
                v.append(j)
                if i+1 == len(v):
                    y.append(v)
                    c = v[1:]
                    v = c
        print(y)
    else:
        break
```

---

ОШИБКА

```
Failed test #1 of 9. Runtime error

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:
a b
Correct output:
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b']]

Your code output:
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b']]

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 7, in <module>
    x = input().split()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Если на вход программе подаётся строка текста, зачем Вы пытаетесь прочитать несколько строк, используя цикл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно читать только одну строку из стандартного ввода:

```py
y = [[]]
v = []
counter = 0


x = input().split()

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    v = []
    for j in x:
        v.append(j)
        if i+1 == len(v):
            y.append(v)
            c = v[1:]
            v = c
print(y)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас добрый и мудрый человек! Приятных Вам праздников.

Answer (score 0):

Да, читать надо было только одну строку. Кроме того, в Питоне есть специальная нотация чтобы извлекать подсписки из списка - `x[i:j]`. Если ею воспользоваться то получится что-то вроде:

```
def sublists(x):
    yield x[:0]
    for s in range(1, len(x) + 1):
        for i in range(len(x) + 1 - s):
            yield x[i:i + s]

print(list(sublists(input().split())))
```

> ```
> $ echo a b c | python sublists.py
> [[], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
> ```

**P.S.** В постановке задачи есть одно нелогичное место. Строго говоря в список входит не один пустой подсписок, а `n + 1` штука. Это пустые подсписки начинающиеся с разных мест списка. Но в постановке для пустых подсписков сделано исключение, и требуется вывести только один из них.